# Chow ring isomorphic to homology ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

I heard an algebraic geometry professor say that the Chow ring is usually isomorphic to the homology ring for cases we care about in application. However, I cannot find many results about this, beyond that it is isomorphic for $\mathbb{P}^n$. Is it isomorphic for things like products and blow-ups? What is the most general statement that I can use?

I am especially interested in blow-ups. I would like to understand the negative self-intersection of the exceptional divisor (i.e. in the blow up of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ at a point) but I want to use the "differential geometry" proof that goes by integrating the first Chern class, which should be on the topology side.

Comment: Even for smooth projective curves of positive genus this is not true. It is true for projective plane blown up at a point.

Comment: Alright, good to know, thanks! Do you have a reference/something I can follow up on for the blow-up case? Does the isomorphism follow from some theorem or did people just compute them both independently?

Comment: You could try *3264 and all that - a second course in algebraic geometry* by Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: Alas, that's what I'm trying to read right now XD They do have a section but I cannot find a strong positive statement about when they are isomorphic, perhaps because no such statement exists! Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @hedgehogenthusiast you may be interested in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151341/for-which-varieties-is-the-natural-map-from-the-chow-ring-to-integral-cohomology

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the link! As stated on that question, Example 19.1.11 in Fulton's Intersection Theory seems like the right thing.